# run test classes using xctest framework from a class

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ios9.3

i am facing a problem. I want to do a ui test for my application.

i have written six test class where my test cases are included.

I can run my test cases using

```
"command U" or the clicking in the run button.
```

But i don't want to do like this.

I want to run my test classes using code i mean using

```
xctest because after complete my execution, i have to do another task.
```

can anyone please give an example how i can run my test classes using xctest codding from a class file.

i dont want to use shell script or jenkins, i want it by using xctest framework.

Comment: What is the follow-on task?

Comment: @JonReid , after complete my task, i have to send email and other tasks

Answer (score 1):

Running tests with xcodebuild
The xcodebuild command-line tool drives tests just like the Xcode IDE. Run xcodebuild with the action test and specify different destinations with the -destination argument. For example, to test MyApp on the local OS X “My Mac 64 Bit,” specify that destination and architecture with this command:

```
> xcodebuild test -project MyAppProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp -destination 'platform=OS X,arch=x86_64'
```

If you have development-enabled devices plugged in, you can call them out by name or id. For example, if you have an iPod touch named “Development iPod touch” connected that you want to test your code on, you use the following command:

```
> xcodebuild test -project MyAppProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp -destination 'platform=iOS,name=Development iPod touch'
```

Tests can run in Simulator, too. Use the simulator to target different form factors, operating systems, and OS versions easily. Simulator destinations can be specified by name or id. For example:

```
> xcodebuild test -project MyAppProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp -destination 'platform=Simulator,name=iPhone,OS=8.1'
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/08-automation.html)

Comment: how i can do this in my ios app?

Comment: actually is this possible to run xcode build command to run in ios project using swift?

Comment: yes, it is possible to run xcodebuild to run swift project. Just open your terminal, go to project folder, run the command above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit your Xcode scheme.
2. Click the disclosure triangle next to "Test" to reveal more options.
3. Select "Post-actions"
4. Click '+' to add any actions to run after tests are complete.

[image]

As you can see, your choices are to run a script, or send a simple email. For more information on configuring actions, see https://michele.io/the-project-file-part-2/

Comment: thanks for ur help @Jon Reid  i did it so far but i am facing problem about attaching file and adding multiple user thats why i am trying in another way. if i add multiple user in scheme like : user1@abc.com, user2@abc.com  it does not send email.

Comment: can u give any suggestion or link regarding these problems ?